# Sync multiple MediaItems

Tags: c#

I have an application that plays for wmv files at the same time - they are all together controlled by one slider and play/pause/stop buttons.

I am using the code below to control the video via the slider - problem is, that they get out of sync as soon as using the slider two-three times or often. Anybody got an idea on how to fix this?

```
    private void slider1_DragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        videos[0].Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(slider1.Value);

        foreach (MediaElement elem in videos)
        {
            elem.Position = videos[0].Position;
            elem.Play();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

LOL, the problem is that `videos[0]` starts to play immediately, even before the remainder of the elements start to play. None of the elements will be in sync, because you're calling the `Position` and then `Play` right afterwards, on an element-by-element basis. Try this instead:

```
private void slider1_DragCompleted(object sender,     
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var realPosition = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(slider1.Value);

    foreach (var elem in videos)
    {
        elem.Position = realPosition;
    }

    foreach (var elem in videos)
    {
        elem.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Thx very much for your reply! Actually, I indeed wanted the files to start one by one and get the current position of the first video when they start (to keep it as a "leader", no matter how long the other videos need to start). Unfortunately, your example doesn't seem to make it better...